# Swagger codegen to omit empty string

Tags: c#, rest, swagger-codegen

I user swagger codegen cli 2.4.8 to generate a client for a rest api with these flags.

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i http://xxxxxxx.com/swagger/v1/swagger.json -l csharp -c config.json -o c:\dev\xxxxxClient
```

Where config.json contains

```
{
    "packageName": "xxxxxxxxx.Client",
    "targetFramework": "v5.0"
}
```

Everything works well, but I want it to omit an empty string that is not required.
I do the following

```
var subScriptionResponse = await subscriptionApiClient.UpdateAsync(dbLicense.PublicIdString, new UpdateSubscriptionRequest() { CancelAtPeriodEnd = delete });
```

However the **UpdateSubscriptionRequest** has two properties and the generated constructor looks like this

```
public UpdateSubscriptionRequest(bool? cancelAtPeriodEnd = default(bool?), string taxId = default(string))
{
    this.CancelAtPeriodEnd = cancelAtPeriodEnd;
    this.TaxId = taxId;
}
```

That means I cannot omit taxId which is not required. However, if set it must be a valid value. So the rest api just replies with

> You passed an empty string for 'default_tax_rates[0]'. We assume empty
>   values are an attempt to unset a parameter; however
>   'default_tax_rates[0]' cannot be unset. You should remove
>   'default_tax_rates[0]' from your request or supply a non-empty value.

I would like to update the **CancelAtPeriodEnd** without sending with the **TaxId**

Any idea on how I can make this work with swagger codegen?